# Property values in yml file not loading into a class in springboot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

Please find the code below for application.yml

```
decrypt: /Users/Blahblah/Bleh
```

The above property we're trying to read into a Class please find the code for PropertyLoader.java

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class PropertyLoader implements InitializingBean{
    @Value("${decrypt}")
    private String decryptPath;
    <--->
}
```

the value decryptPath is always null. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Is application.yml in src/main/resources folder or somewhere else

Comment: could you paste the complete application.yml?

Comment: @sumitsingh Everything is indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly application.yml should be under the `src/main/resources/application.yml`.

If you want to use this variables in constructor, you don't. Because spring inject @Value annotated variables after the construction.But if you want to do in constructer you can do like :

```
public class PropertyLoader implements InitializingBean{

    private String decryptPath;

    public PropertyLoader(@Value("${decrypt}") decrypPath) {
     this.decryptPath = decryptPath;

     }
    }
```

Comment: Okey then, could you try @PostContruct

Comment: @PostConstruct
 public void initIt()  {
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

It turns out since this class is implementing `InitializingBean`, the properties object won't be initialized until this class has completed execution. The @Value will always return null.